# Sort array with custom keys

Tags: php

How to sort php array with custom keys?

```
$arr  = array("41" => "10", "20" => "5");
```

I need to sort array by values with saving keys.

I tried `sort()` but it changes keys to associative 0..n

Comment: use asort instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) for sorting array based on values:

```
asort($arr);
```

Comment: I need to sort array **by values** with **saving keys**.